The image of the monodromy of the twisted product
Given spaces $A,B$ and a group $G$ acts properly discontinuously and freely on $A,B$ respectively, then there is a fiber bundle from the twisted product: $B\to (A\times B)/G \to A/G$. Then what can we say about the image of the monodromy representation $\phi:\pi_1(A/G)\to \text{Mod}(B)$? It looks like the image is just $G$, but I am not sure.

Do you know the answer when $A=EG$? i.e. the universal cover for a $K(G,1)$ space?

@AndresMejia, I don't know. Could you please explain the answer?
